# Matching numbers for substitution in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have this little script:

```
my @list = ('R3_05_foo.txt','T3_12_foo_bar.txt','01.txt');

foreach (@list) {
    s/(\d{2}).*\.txt$/$1.txt/;
    s/^0+//;
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

The expected output would be

```
5.txt
12.txt
1.txt
```

But instead, I get

```
R3_05.txt
T3_12.txt
1.txt
```

The last one is fine, but I cannot fathom why the regex gives me the string start for `$1` on this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
foreach (@list) {
    s/^.*?_?(?|0(\d)|(\d{2})).*\.txt$/$1.txt/;
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

Explanations:

I use here the branch reset feature (i.e. `(?|...()...|...()...)`) that allows to put several capturing groups in a single reference ( `$1` here ). So, you avoid using a second replacement to trim a zero from the left of the capture.

To remove all from the begining before the number, I use :

```
.*?     # all characters zero or more times 
        # ( ? -> make the * quantifier lazy to match as less as possible)
_?      # an optional underscore
```

Note that you can ensure that you have only 2 digits adding a lookahead to check if there is not a digit that follows:

```
s/^.*?_?(?|0(\d)|(\d{2}))(?!\d).*\.txt$/$1.txt/;
```

`(?!\d)` means *not followed by a digit*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your substitution regex does not cover the whole string, so only part of the string is substituted. But you are using a rather complex solution for a simple problem.

It seems that what you want is to read two digits from the string, and then add `.txt` to the end of it. So why not just do that?

```
my @list = ('R3_05_foo.txt','T3_12_foo_bar.txt','01.txt');

for (@list) {
    if (/(\d{2})/) {
        $_ = "$1.txt";
    }
}
```

To overcome the leading zero effect, you can force a conversion to a number by adding zero to it:

```
$_ = 0+$1 . ".txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your regular expression. Try using this code:

```
my @list = ('R3_05_foo.txt','T3_12_foo_bar.txt','01.txt');

foreach (@list) {
    s/.*(\d{2}).*\.txt$/$1.txt/;
    s/^0+//;
    print $_ . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I had that before and I only got a single digit in the output.

Comment: Sure? My output: perl test.pl
5.txt
12.txt
1.txt

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first part in your `s///` matches, what you think it does, but that the second part isn't replacing what you think it should. `s///` will only replace what was previously matched. Thus to replace something like `T3_` you will have to match that too.

```
s/.*(\d{2}).*\.txt$/$1.txt/;
```